# Difference between one way binding and two way binding in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Could you explain the difference between `One-way Data Binding` and `Two-way Data Binding` with an example and which situation we used?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**One-Way Data Binding**

`ng-bind` has one-way data binding `(Model($scope) --> View)`
Eg.
    `ng-bind="myText"` OR `{{ myText }}`

which displays the scope value `$scope.myText` inserted into HTML where `myText` is a scope variable name.(E.g., Model -> View)

**Two-Way Data Binding**

`ng-model` is intended to be put mostly inside form elements and has two-way data binding

`(Model($scope) --> View and View --> Model($scope))`

Eg. `<input name="firstname" ng-model="firstname"/>`

When you interact with form element `firstname` to which `ng-model` interact with `$scope.firstname` and update the corresponding view automatically by `Digest` cycle.(E.g., Model -> View and View -> Model)

**One-Time Data Binding**

The new syntax adds `::` in front of any values(**One-way or Two-way**), which declares we want `one time binding`:

```
<p>
  {{ ::firstname }}
</p>
```

Once `firstname` becomes defined and contains a value, AngularJS will `unbind` it and any Model updates won’t affect the View.

Eg. When using **ng-if**

```
<div ng-if="::user.firstname"></div>
```

When using **ng-class**

```
<div ng-class="::{ 'active': user.firstname }"></div>
```

When usine **ng-repeat**

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="user in ::users"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The definition confuses "one-time" binding with "one-way" binding. One-time binding only changes once. One-way binding continuously updates the DOM as the model changes.

Comment: The first version of the answer was better. Problems were introduced in subsequent edits.

Comment: @georgeawg one-way binding is completely different than one-time binding. Both One-way and two-way binding when the model update, view automatically update.  But one-time is different. The new syntax adds :: in front of any values, which declares we want one time binding. Once "firstname" becomes defined and contains a value, Angular will unbind it and any Model updates won’t affect the View.  (E.g) {{ ::firstname }}

Answer (score 12):

One way binding is bind the data from model to view. Also two way binding is bind the data from model to view and view to model.

Answer (score 10):

data binding in UI is the binding of UI fields to a data model. There are two approaches of data binding : one way data binding and two way data binding

one way data binding -> model is the single source of truth . whatever happens on UI triggers a message to model to update a part of data. So data flows in single direction and which becomes easy to understand.

two way data binding -> any change in UI field updates the model and any change in model updates the UI field.

one way data binding is better approach because of unidirectional flow of data. Also only model has the access to change the application state.