# AngularJS How to convert component two-way binding to one-way binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

Hello what is right way to convert two way data binding in angularJS to one way?

I have component

```
import template from './test.component.html';
import controller from './test.controller';

export const DateWrapperComponent = {
  bindings: {
    test: '='
  },
  template,
  controller
};
```

controller

```
export default function TestController($scope) {
  /* ngInject */

  $scope.$watch('$ctrl.test', () => {
     console.log(this);
  });
}
```

and view:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.test">
```

what is right way to convert it?

Comment: [`ng-bind="$ctrl.test"`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) ? ..... but if this is an `input` why to use one way binding, maybe you want to set it to `readonly`?

Comment: nope, I have task to convert it to one way data binding, input is not readonly :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between one way binding and two way binding in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38626156/difference-between-one-way-binding-and-two-way-binding-in-angularjs)

Comment: The proposed duplicate does not apply. It does not explain how the two types of bindings work in components or how to change them.

Answer (score 1):

### Making the Migration to Angular 2+ Easier

Convert AngularJS two-way binding with `=` to use one-way binding with `<` for inputs, and expression binding with `&` for outputs:

```
app.component("testComponent", {
    bindings: {
        sample: '<',
        sampleChange: '&',
    },
    template: `
        <fieldset>
            <input ng-model="$ctrl.sample"
                   ng-change="$ctrl.sampleChange({$event: $ctrl.sample})"
            />
        </fieldset>
    `,
});
```

#### Usage:

```
<test-component sample="test" sample-change="test=$event">
</test-component>

TEST={{test}}
```

The reason for doing this is that it makes the migration to Angular 2+ easier. Angular 2+ doesn't have two-way binding with `=`.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based application architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture)

---

### Angular 2+ two-way binding

With Angular 2+, two-way binding (banana in a box):

```
<app-sizer [(size)]="fontSizePx"></app-sizer>
```

Is syntactic sugar for:

```
<app-sizer [size]="fontSizePx" (sizeChange)="fontSizePx=$event"></app-sizer>
```

For more information, see

- [Angular.io Guide - Template Syntax - Two-way binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---)

Answer (score 0):

Its seems like you wanted to pass the `test` value to your component form the consumer component, but when that value gets change by your component it shouldn't be reflected back to consumer component value. So you could use `<`(one way binding) instead of `=`(two way binding) inside `bindings` option. Inside binding `<` make sure that the data will flow in unidirectional way (top to bottom).

```
export const DateWrapperComponent = {
  bindings: {
    test: '<'
  },
  template,
  controller
};
```

> Note: This feature is applicable from `1.5.x` version when `component`
>   API got introduced in AngularJS

Comment: but I need to send data from view to component not from component to view in one way data binding, it is possible?

Comment: @axlpl not sure what you asked? can you please elaborate a bit?